# Add files from selected directories to 7-zip archive while keeping relative directory structure in archive

Tags: powershell, relative-path, 7zip

I am trying to zip files that are in directories that have subdirectories and I can't figure out how to zip the files and not the subdirectories.

Here is the current setup:

```
C:\users\user\appdata\local\folder\
```

Inside of this folder, I need 3 out of the 20 or so folders that are in there so I used the Get-Childitem to accomplish this:

```
GCI C:\users\user\appdata\local\folder | ? {$_.name -like "*folder*}
```

Now that I have that, I don't want the subdirectories and just want the files that are sitting in the folder itself. I have not found a way to do this, but I have gotten close with using this:

```
& "C:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" "a" "D:\TestBackup\Zipfile.7z" (GCI C:\users\user\appdata\local\folder | ? {$_.name -like "*folder*} | select -expandproperty FullName)
```

But this gives me the entire contents of the folder. I want to keep the structure so that it looks like this:

```
folder 1\files
folder 2\files
folder 3\files
```

I hope I am explaining myself well. The files are all different types of extensions so I was wanting a blanket way to do this or to exclude the subdirectories when zipping.

Comment: I am not looking for .zip though, but .7z which only 7zip accomplishes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to consult the [FAQ](https://7-zip.org/faq.html) to get this right:

> 7-Zip stores only relative paths of files (without drive letter
> prefix). You can **change current folder to folder that is common for**
> **all files** that you want to compress and then you can use relative
> paths:
>
> ```text
> cd /D C:\dir1\   
> 7z.exe a c:\a.7z file1.txt dir2\file2.txt
> ```

**Solution:**

```
# Set base directory that is common for all files
Push-Location 'C:\users\user\appdata\local\folder'

# Get names of directories that match filter
$folderNames = (Get-ChildItem -Directory -Filter '*folder*').Name

# Call 7-zip, passing the list of directory names.
& 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' a 'D:\TestBackup\Zipfile.7z' $folderNames

# Restore current directory
Pop-Location
```

**Remarks:**

- `Push-Location` sets the current directory, while `Pop-Location` restores the previous current directory. Changing the current directory is crucial for this solution, as explained by the 7-zip FAQ. It is also the only way to set the base directory for `Resolve-Path -Relative`.
- Pass `-Directory` or `-File` to `Get-ChildItem` if you are only interested in either directories or files.
- Use `-Filter` instead of `Where-Object` (alias `?`) if you only need simple wildcard filtering. `-Filter` is faster because it uses the FileSystem provider which filters at a lower API level, which avoids PowerShell overhead.